Stochastic optimization for day trading
Suppose we have a forecast of price changes for a set of assets and we want to day trade based on it. I'm guessing this would involve some kind of stochastic optimization - with presumably a decision variable on how to adjust the portfolio for every time point (so probably thousands to tens of thousands of variables)?
Are there any books/references on the formulations/optimization strategies on this particular problem?

Hi: I can't answer with certainity but my guess is that you can do some kind of optimization similar to that in the markowitz framework. You've got possible trades. Hopefully each of those have expected returns and variances. So, you can maximize the return subject to some risk or just create the whole efficient frontier. If the trades don't have expected returns and variances, then you've got an interesting problem but one would need more details on what you do have to say anything possibly useful.

I read it again and you clearly have forecasts which can be viewed as expected returns. The question is whether you have estimates of the variance and covariances of those forecasts. This is often the piece that's missing and this makes standard markowitz portfolio optimization not possible.
